# CA certificate location

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have **1) X509 Certificate (child)** ->   **Authentication  CA (parent)** certificate and ->  **root CA (root)** certificate.

Questions:

1. Can I  retrieve  this **Authentication CA** certificate from current X509Certificate certificate?
2. when I double click my certificate, I see the hierarchy of certificates. And  from here, I can open each one. So, can I get  **Authentication  CA certificate** location or something like that from that certificate?
3. what ways can you recommend , in order to retrieve **Authentication  CA** certificate?

I need to do this using java code. not key tool or something like that. I have Root CA certificate and  X509 Certificate (child). and I need parent of child certificate.

I use bouncycastle and java's classes in order to work with certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An X.509 certificate does not contain within it the certificate of the issuing CA. If you double-click on the child certificate and see a chain, this suggests that your operating system has access to the intermediate certificates (somehow).

If you need a chain of certificates, then you need to retrieve this from some external source. Many protocols (such as SSL) will provide a full certificate chain by default. The answer really depends upon the context of your problem, which is not clear from your question.

Comment: Duncan Jones
I was thinking that I could get intermediate certificates from child certificate. thank you very much. That was answer that I was searching.